# Objects communication

Tags: c#, .net, controls

I have a custom user control with a `bool Selected` variable, and code that checks if it is selected, and if so it highlights it, if it's not selected, it hides the highlight. simple enough.

Now, I have a panel that's filled with that object, and I need it to work similar to any files explorer (such as Windows Explorer). I mean by that, that if you click the item, it selects itself. that's not a problem, it's just a mouse click. the problem comes in when the user wants to select other items **instead**.

What I basically want is:

Whenever the user clicks on an item, all other items deselects and such.

I was trying to find the best way to do it, all that came to my mind is have a parent class that directs those operations (changes the bool, and call the update function) but it seems too sloppy, and maybe a bit complicated. any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't fully read, sorry. What exactly are you selecting...? Files, pictures?

Comment: which platform? winform, wpf???

Comment: You're basically asking how to implement single select in a WPF items control?

Comment: @moowiz2020 I mentioned at the first sentence "I have a custom control". Shoaib Shaikh This goes for WPF but I could use an answer for WinForms aswell. Tormod Yes, I could go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach would be a "collection" component, which manages rules such as how many could be selected and exposes useful information and events (such as SelectedItem and SelectedItemChanged).

Comment: Could you suggest a way to "manually" achieve this? (since I'm looking for tweaking this a little bit)

Comment: Creating a new collection component would allow you to reuse this somewhere else; however, a quick & dirty solution would be to put this management code directly in your form. I strongly recommend you create a dedicated collection component, however.

Comment: I described what I did in my answer, but I think you should still get best answer because you did answer it very well - So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my first idea the best I could find (as "reinventing the wheel", if not, overslacked answer was great for this case).
I created a class that has a list of those user-controls, and gave the user-controls a property for that list.

And so when I want to select a user-control, I had in its click event a function that's inside the class I created which deselects all the controls under it, and selects the one I clicked.

It did seem a little sloppy as I expected but I'm sure that if I was really giving my mind into it I could make it plain and organized, so in case anybody else wonders and needs this information.